# more efficient way to parse kubenetes pod name

Tags: json, performance, jq

I have the following code which works but the `| . [ ]` section looks redundant.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I could remove that code - preferably with an explanation as to why it's ineficient?

```
 kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=esl-mops -o json |\
    jq -r '[.items[] | {name:.metadata.name} ] | . [ ] .name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saying that your intuition is telling you that there's a simpler and more efficient way to get the .metadata.name values, then lucky you, because the pipeline could be streamlined to just:

```
.items[] | .metadata.name
```

This avoids all the overhead of constructing an array, constructing an object, and then dismantling everything.

By the way, this illustrates quite nicely the value of jq being stream-oriented.  This often helps make it possible to have simple solutions to simple problems, and to achieve an efficient solution if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for that - i hate to look at ugly in basic code. Great tool.